# How to set Android SDK, NDK and JDK paths in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: android, ubuntu, path, terminal, environment-variables

Below is my .bashrc file

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples
$export=$PATH:./home/ssrp/workspace/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
$export PATH=$PATH:./home/ssrp/workspace/android-sdk-linux/tools
$export JAVA_HOME=./usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk
$export NDK=./home/ssrp/workspace/android-ndk-r9
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "$debian_chroot" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi
```

The NDK and SDK folders are located as they are in the path in the .bashrc file, But it gives me the following output when I opened the terminal;

```
bash: =/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:./home/ssrp/workspace/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools: No such file or directory
bash: PATH=/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:./home/ssrp/workspace/android-sdk-linux/tools: No such file or directory
bash: JAVA_HOME=./usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk: No such file or directory
bash: NDK=./home/ssrp/workspace/android-ndk-r9: No such file or directory
ssrp@ssrp-PC:~$
```

What could I be doing wrong here, could anyone specify?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For JAVA_HOME remove the first dot in the path. For NDK and PATH remove ./home/ssrp and put ~ instead. it should look like this:

```
$export PATH=$PATH:~/workspace/android-sdk-linux/tools:~/workspace/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
$export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk
$export NDK=~/workspace/android-ndk-r9
```