# Download android-ndk-r9-linux-x86

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, android-ndk, ubuntu-10.04

I am trying to find somewhere link to download `android-ndk-r9-linux-x86` but unfortunately all my tries failed.

Can someone provide me a working link, so I can Download `Android NDK R9` for `linux x86`.

Comment: are you for real ? https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html#Downloads ?

Comment: i am very curious, though, what exactly have you tried that could possibly fail?

Comment: @njzk2 the **specific version requested** is not in fact visibly available from that page. Perhaps the poster doesn't need that exact version, **but then perhaps they do, for example to replicate a bug**

Comment: yes, but the url for this particular version is very straightforwardly obtained from the url of version r9c.

Comment: In this case yes, but "what exactly have you tried that could possibly fail" implies reading the directions, not guessing URLs.

Comment: Also, the URL style changed with r10. Don't be rude in your comments please.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The specific version you requested, r9 without a letter suffix, although not linked on the download page, currently appears to be able to be obtained by taking one of the current-version links and simply editing it to change the version number to the one you want.  However, it's not a given that this will continue to be the case - the android downloads seem to move around a fair amount.

http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r9-linux-x86.tar.bz2

Of course if you don't need that *exact* version you can simply follow the link to a *current* version on the download page.

Comment: Thanks, This is what I need, as on official website I can't find 9R, only 9rc and 9rb, thanks !!!

Comment: Hi Chris, Can you please tell me how to compile linphone for android on Ubuntu 12.04? i am not getting any document. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The link from [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html#Installing) seems to work:

[`http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r9c-linux-x86.tar.bz2`](http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r9c-linux-x86.tar.bz2)

You can then set up with the instructions [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html#Installing). You may also find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608610/how-to-set-android-sdk-ndk-and-jdk-paths-in-ubuntu-12-04) of help.